# LOAD DATA INFILE : import only certain columns according to their name in the csv file

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv file that I would like to transfer to a MySQL table, but the column order can vary, and additional columns can appear.

I want to be able to get the following result in mysql :

```
csql1 | csql2
-------------
foo1  | foo2
bar1  | bar2
```

whether my csv file is

```
csv1,csv2
foo1,foo2
bar1,bar2
```

or

```
csv2,csv1
foo2,foo1
bar2,bar1
```

or even

```
csv1,csv2,csv3
foo1,foo2,uselessdata
bar1,bar2,uselessdata
```

All the examples I could find online explicitely express the columns in the csv file :

```
(@csv1,@csv2)
SET csql1=@csv1,csql2=@csv2
```

Which forces me to know the order of the columns in csv file, and does not let me use the column names that are present in the csv file

Is this possible with MySQL or should I preprocess the files to have the correct number  and order of column ?

If it's any clearer, what I would like to do is 
    SET csql1 = column which has the same csv1 in the csv file but not necessarily the first position

Comment: Does the CSV file differ all the time in the ordering? What options have you tried before to perform this?

Comment: The csv column ordering could be modified, and I will run this request on 40 different csv files which makes it important for me not to have a silent error if column order is modified in one csv.  I have tried to work within documentation of LOAD DATA INFILE, but it never mentions if/how we can import and use column names.